# Write access to jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins

I am currently able to read from the jenkins workspace e.g. to print out all the files contained in

```
/var/jenkins_home/jobs/[jobName]/workspace
```

Is it possible to also add files to the workspace during a build?

Comment: This is the whole point of like.. doing a build..? So what's your problem? Have you actually tried it?

Comment: It's absolutely you can do that.  if it's not allowed, how to put source  code from github to jenkins job workspace. you can use script you like to write file to job workspace.

Comment: @StephenKing during the test, files are downloaded on a docker container so I tried using:

`docker cp [containerName]:/home/seluser/Downloads /var/jenkins_home/jobs/[jobName]/workspace`

But nothing got copied to the workspace. This is why I was wondering if it is actually possible or I’m missing something. I tried a similar command locally on my laptop and it worked. But doesn’t work on Jenkins workspace.

Comment: So you are doing the copy inside a docker container? Do you know about volumes and that this container has an own file system?

Comment: If you just use Jenkins pipelines, the working directory inside the container is actually the workspace of the Jenkins job (mounted as a volume). So feels like you are doing weird things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.. when ever you build a project it will generate artifacts and placed into workspace only.. similarly you can use any shell/batch script or any plugins to add new files to the work space while running the jenkins job.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Everything under the workspace of the job is accessible by the job i.e. create, delete, modify etc. The job will have complete access to all directories, files inside its workspace. For printing the workspace location, please execute this command inside the `Execute Shell` block.

```
echo $WORKSPACE
```

Above command will print the location of the job's base workspace location. You can go to any directory inside the job also. ex:

```
cd '<path to ur custom location>'
ls -ltra
```

This will simply lists all the files in your custom location. Hope this helps.